# Leaflet ionic position errors

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, leaflet, angular-leaflet-directive

From some time on I am getting

```
[Log] PositionError (mapController.js, line 141)
code: 2
message: ""
__proto__: PositionErrorPrototype
```

in Safari on OSX and iOS when I run my Leaflet.js based app and the [example](http://ionic-leafletjs-map-demo.divshot.io/#/app/map) that it's based on. 
When I started the project, this was not the case. It happens when I try to get the current location by calling

```
$cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition().then(function (position) {
...
}
```

Any ideas? Is it reproducible?

Edit:
I figured it's returning `PositionError.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE` as defined in the [specs](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.5.0/cordova_geolocation_geolocation.md.html#PositionError).
I added options to the request `{ maximumAge: 3000, timeout: 5000, enableHighAccuracy: true }` hoping it would extend the timeout span to 5sec., but I keep getting the error immediately after request...

Safari 8.0.6 OSX 10.10.3 XCode 6.3.2

It works fine with Chrome, but I plan to deploy this on iOS & Android